# One index automatically updates when other list is being updated

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whenever I'm updating the `newnumber[index]`, the `number[index]` is also updated even tho I'm not updating it.

Here is my code for further reference:

```
number = [1]
newnumber = [1]
row = int(input("Enter the desired number of rows: "))
for i in range(row):
    print("\n\nFor loop", i)
    print("The number: ", number)
    for i in range(len(number) - 1):
        newnumber[i+1] = number[i] + number[i+1]
        print("number",i, "is equal to", number[i])
        print("number",i + 1, "is equal to", number[i+1])
        print("newnumber",i + 1, "is equal to", newnumber[i+1])

    newnumber.append(number[0])
    print("The newnumber: ", newnumber)
    number = newnumber
```

I'm getting an output of:

```
For loop 1
The number:  [1, 1]
number 0 is equal to 1
number 1 is equal to 2
newnumber 1 is equal to 2
The newnumber:  [1, 2, 1]
```

As you can see, I'm trying to update `newnumber[1]` by adding `number[0]` and `number[1]`. However, number 1 is also being updated thus giving me the wrong output. Why is that? I'm thinking that `newnumber[1]` and `number[1]` is somehow connected thus when `newnumber[1]` is updated the `number[1]` is also updated.

I'm new in programming perse and saw that python is more newbie friendly. Already did my research but saw that it is more on copying the entire list and not the specific index only.

Comment: `number = newnumber` is not copying the list

Comment: What's the desired output???

Comment: @Chris_Rands thank you so much! This answered my question.

Comment: @U8-Forward I'm trying to make a pascal triangle that will display the first _row_ .